What are my groups in kubernetes (GKE) on GCP?
The answer is supposedly easy:
$ kubectl auth whoami

But it says that I belong only to system:authenticated. That's not pretty informative, and I believe I must belong to system:masters. Why? Because I created the cluster and it's pretty basic:
resource "google_container_cluster" "test" {
  name = "test"
  location = "europe-central2-a"
  remove_default_node_pool = true
  initial_node_count = 1
  network = google_compute_network.test.self_link
  subnetwork = google_compute_subnetwork.test.self_link
  ip_allocation_policy {}
}

resource "google_container_node_pool" "test" {
  name = "test"
  cluster = google_container_cluster.test.id
  location = google_container_cluster.test.location
  initial_node_count = 1
}

Also:
$ kubectl auth can-i \* \* --all-namespaces
yes

I was able to reproduce it with sh and it still returns system:authenticated. What am I missing here?
